# Optimized the Query in Union all

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Here am explain my problem with sample.

Table names `ledg,bill,vocu`

Columns

```
 Ledg

    id
    name

bill
   id
   amt

vouc

   id
   amt
```

Here i want to select name which amt is greater than zero in bill and vouc. But bill and vouc does not have same id. And i want to show the which amt is greater than zero only.

So i tried like this

```
select *  
from ledg g inner join vouc v on v.id=g.id 

union all

select *  
from ledg g inner join bill b on b.id=g.id
```

Its work correctly. Can i get same result in a single query or any effective query?

SAMPLE

```
insert into ledg(id,name) values(1,'aa'),
(2,'bb'),
(3,'cc');


insert into bill(id,amt) values(1,10),(2,-10);

insert into vouc(id,amt) values(3,30);
```

OUTPUT

```
NAME  Amt

aa    10
cc    30
```

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  Your question seems to be about amounts greater than zero, yet the query you say is working has no such comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `ledg` rows where the value is greater than `0` in the other two tables, you could do:

```
select g.*
from ledg g
where exists (select 1 from vouc v where v.id = l.id and v.amt > 0) and
      exists (select 1 from bill b where b.id = l.id and b.amt > 0);
```

This can take good advantage of indexes on the `id` column in `vouc` and `bill`.

Comment: Thanks sir for your valuable time. can i get same result in single query. it is possible?

Comment: @Sathish . . . This is a single query; I don't know what you mean.

Comment: i mean one select query sir